# Laravel - Storing notification settings per user with different channels

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, php-8

I am developing a fairly simple application, where I want my users to be able to subscribe to notifications. So the system should:

- Send notifications when a certain event they are subscribed to happens.
- Send notifications to the channels they have selected (email or slack)

Below is an example of different notifications they each user can subscribe to.

[image]

I am wondering how to do this using Laravel. My first idea was to:

1. Create a `notifications` JSON column on the `users` table, and store it like (probably using the learnings from the [Managing Mass User Settings](https://laracasts.com/lessons/managing-mass-user-settings) lesson.)

```json
{
  "todo": {
    "assigned": [
      {
        "email": true,
        "slack": true
      }
    ],
    "mentioned": [
      {
        "email": true,
        "slack": true
      }
    ]
  },
  "project": {
    "created": [
      {
        "email": true,
        "slack": true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

However, I am unsure if this is good practice. Further, I am also a unsure on how to actually send out the notifications dynamically.

For sending it out, I want to use Laravels notification system:

```php
Notification::send($user, new TodoCreated($todo));
```

I am not sure if this is the best way, or if it makes more sense to use an Event/Listener setup? A

Also, can I utilize the `via()` method on the `Notification` class to dynamically specify the channels according to the user settings?

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think a many-to-many relationship would be more suited to this.

```
Tables:

User
 - id

Notifications
 - id

NotificationUser <-- pivot table
 - notifcation_id
 - user_id
 - channel_id

Channel
 - id
 - name
```

To account for these additional fields in the pivot table, define them in the User model relationship:

```
class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The roles that belong to the user.
     */
    public function notifications()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Notification::class)->withPivot(['channel_id']);
    }
}
```

See: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#retrieving-intermediate-table-columns

This way, you can advantage of the relationship methods that Laravel (eloquent) comes with.

i.e:

```
aUser->notifications(); # Getting a list of a user's notifications
aUser->attach(1, ['channel' => 1]); # attaching a notification to the user
```

You can also take advantage of query scopes to retrieve one channel of notifications for the user etc

See: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#query-scopes

Then use the model/listener pattern as you had planned.

Comment: But how can I then control the different channels? I.e an user have notification type 1 enabled and want to send that to both Slack and Email?

Comment: Additional fields can be added to the pivot table. For example, you could have a `type` on the `NotificationUser` pivot table which could be a one-to-many to a `NotificationTypes` table, where you could have `id: 1, name: 'email'; id: 2 name: 'slack'` etc. See  https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#filtering-queries-via-intermediate-table-columns

Comment: I updated my answer to account for channels.

Comment: When adding `withPivot('channel')` I get: `unknown column 'notification_user.channel'`

Comment: Did you add that column to your notification user migration? If you are doing a one to many relationship then it should be channel_id also. Sorry, I put channel by mistake.

Comment: I have added the column `channel_id` to the `notification_user` table

Comment: It should be channel_id, not channel, my bad.

Comment: But how can I then access the channel relation through the pivot table? I cannot do: `$notification->pivot->channel` and get the row in the `channels` table, but only get the channel id.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228105/discussion-between-gclark18-and-oliverbj).